# Javascript function to change Caption

Tags: javascript, html, button

```js
function change_text(a){

    if (a == Canberra){
        var x = document.getElementById("a");
        document.x.innerHTML = "Correct!";
    }

    else{
        var x = document.getElementById("a");
        document.x.innerHTML = "Incorrect!";
    }
}
```

```html
  <figure>
             <button onclick="change_text(Melbourne)"> Melbourne! </button>
             <figcaption id="Melbourne"> &nbsp; </figcaption>
     </figure>


    <figure>
            <button onclick="change_text(Canberra)"> Canberra! </button>
            <figcaption id = "Canberra"> &nbsp; </figcaption>
    </figure>
```

Hello, i am new to JS/HTML. I intended to create some buttons with a captions. But the captions should only appear when a corresponding button is clicked. So far it was the easiest to take the figure tag, to have the caption right below the button. The function should take as parameters, the city name and depending on which button pressed the caption should show/change to correct/incorrect.

I am really new to this and i do not understand if anything here what i did makes sense, so i am thankful for any help.

Comment: String literals have to be inside quotes, always. You're doing this correctly here: `"Correct!";` Now do the same in your onclicks and if tests.

Comment: `var x = document.getElementById("a");` on the other hand needs to be `var x = document.getElementById(a);` because `a` is a variable. Next, you need just `x.innerHTML`, given that `x` already contains the element.

Comment: it should be `document.getElementById(a)` not `"a"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this. Your code have some syntax errors.
First `change_text(sometext)`.
Change this `change_text('sometext')`.
And in if operation change `if(a == sometext)` to `if(a == 'sometext')`
And Change `document.x.inerHTML` to `x.innerHTML`

```js
    function change_text(a){
       
        if (a == "Canberra"){
            var items = document.getElementsByClassName(a);
            console.log(items)
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(items, function(item) {
            item.innerHTML="Correct!";})
        }

        else{   
            var items = document.getElementsByClassName(a);
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(items, function(item) {
            item.innerHTML="Incorrect!";})      
        }
    }
```

```html
    
      <figure>
                 <button onclick="change_text('Melbourne')"> Melbourne! </button>
                 <figcaption class="Melbourne"> &nbsp; </figcaption>
                 <figcaption class="Melbourne"> &nbsp; </figcaption>
         </figure>


        <figure>
                <button onclick="change_text('Canberra')"> Canberra! </button>
                <figcaption class="Canberra"> &nbsp; </figcaption>
                <figcaption class="Canberra"> &nbsp; </figcaption>
        </figure>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for help, now it really works. Do you think there is also a way to get t the individual figcaptions by giving the figures different classes or ID's like. `<figure class = Melbourne>`  and the in JS writing something like. `var x = getElementbyClass(Melbourne)`.  script `x.figcaption.innerHTML = "Incorrect"` ?

Comment: Of cause. the result of ``getElementbyClass`` is array. I edited my answer. I think you can accept my answer if it is helpful. ;)

Answer (score 1):

first problem is you are using `document.getElementById("a")` which is wrong, there are no elements that have the `id` of `"a"` here. so you need to use `document.getElementById(a)` instead

second problem is you are using `document.x.innerHTML` it should be `x.innerHTML` instead

third problem is you need to use quotes `""` in the if statement like this `if (a === "Canberra")`

code:

```js
function change_text(a){

         if (a === "Canberra"){
             var x = document.getElementById(a);
             x.innerHTML = "Correct!";
         }

         else{
             var x = document.getElementById(a);
             x.innerHTML = "Incorrect!";
         }
 }
```

Comment: @George i did test it i just forgot to remove `document` in `document.x.innerHTML` sorry i fixed it now